# Custom ExceptionListener don't catch ConnectionException

Tags: php, symfony, events

I would like to catch `Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException` in my Symfony 2 project. I do a test with wrong parameters for DB access.

To do that, I created a custom ExceptionListener. 
Here is my class :

```
namespace Namespace\Event;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\LoggerInterface;

class ExceptionListener
{

    private $logger;

    private $templateEngine;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger, EngineInterface $templateEngine)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->templateEngine = $templateEngine;
    }

    /**
     * @param GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $exception = $event->getException();

        if ($exception instanceof ConnectionException) {
            //...
        }
 }
```

Here is my problem, My ExceptionListener object is never called. Here is my configuration in services.yml where the listener is registered.

My `AppBundle\Resources\config\services.yml` in top of my file.

```
app.exception.exception_listener:
    class: Namespace\Event\ExceptionListener
    arguments: [ '@logger', '@templating' ]
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }
```

I have an errors stack instead :

```
An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No route to host
```

However, If I take a look to the stack trace, my listener is called :

```
at Container->get('app.exception.exception_listener') in classes.php line 1957
at ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->lazyLoad('kernel.exception') in classes.php line 1925
at ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->getListeners('kernel.exception') in TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 245
at TraceableEventDispatcher->preProcess('kernel.exception') in TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 135
at TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.exception', object(GetResponseForExceptionEvent)) in HttpKernel.php line 221
at HttpKernel->handleException(object(ConnectionException), object(Request), '1') in HttpKernel.php line 75
at HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in ContainerAwareHttpKernel.php line 69
at ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in bootstrap.php.cache line 1505
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in app_dev.php line 42
```

And this is the ouput of `php app/console debug:event-dispatcher kernel.exception`

```
Registered Listeners for "kernel.exception" Event
Order   Callable
Priority
#1      Namespace\Event\ExceptionListener::onKernelException()
0
#2   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelException()
#3      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener::onKernelException()
```

-128

Comment: I'd try to debug. it is not obvious from the data you've provided what could go wrong.

Comment: Is the listener registered and in the correct order? Try running this to see what kernel exception listeners are registered: `php app/console debug:event-dispatcher kernel.exception`

Comment: @Stepashka I know and it's seems to be a random bug. Sometimes after a cache:clear it works.

Comment: @ClickLabs Yes it's registered in the correct worder. I'll edit my answer to output the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify exactly what is happening in your `onKernelException` method.

Make sure it's setting a response in the event. For example, to redirect to a URL:

```
 $response = new RedirectResponse('/some_url');
 $event->setResponse($response);
 return true;
```